# how use viewer-javascript-extract.spreadsheet

Tags: revit-api, revit, autodesk-forge, forge, revit-2015

I have used model derivative API for geometry and data extraction. Now I want to extract model information in excel sheet. I read the post https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-javascript-extract.spreadsheet but I have many questions. Like how to add reference to the ForgeXLS file? And where? What is Forgexlsx? How to call download method? Please explain it in detail.
Similarly on another post https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/model.derivative-csharp-context.menu. I haveID and secret and changed it web.configure. But what next? How to compile the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Extract spreadsheet sample](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-javascript-extract.spreadsheet) is pure JavaScript. All the required files are on the github repo. You need the [ForgeXLS](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-javascript-extract.spreadsheet/blob/master/js/ForgeXLS.js) that implements the extraction process, the other files used are on the [Libraries folder](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-javascript-extract.spreadsheet/tree/master/js/libraries).

The [Context menu](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/model.derivative-csharp-context.menu) sample is bit more complex. As per [readme setup](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/model.derivative-csharp-context.menu#setup), you'll need to compile the whole .NET solution, register the CSShellExtContextMenuHandler.dll on the regasm, which triggers the Translator.exe. You'll need to deploy the TranslatorServer ASP.NET project. Not sure how familiar you are with .NET projects (compile, deployment, etc).

Comment: On the extract spreadsheet sample, look at the Index file (https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-javascript-extract.spreadsheet/blob/master/index.html) and you can use the URN (line 30) and the token endpoint (line 56). The Context Menu requires compile and deploy, which is a bit more complicated, so I would suggest you start with .NET & ASP.NET basics first.